# ¿Cuál es la etimología del topónimo "Guzmán"?

Tags: etimología, nombres-propios, topónimos

Hay por ahí una teoría que dice que el apellido [Guzmán](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guzm%C3%A1n_(apellido)) es una adaptación a la pronunciación española del germánico *gut-mann*, "hombre bueno". La teoría es demasiado bonita como para ser verdad, y de hecho parece que el consenso es que el apellido es simplemente de origen toponímico, dado que provendría del pueblo de [Guzmán](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guzm%C3%A1n_(provincia_de_Burgos)), en la provincia de Burgos. Se basa esto en que el pueblo tuvo su origen en el siglo XI o puede que antes, mientras que el primer registrado (del que se tiene constancia) con el apellido Guzmán sería [Rodrigo Muñoz de Guzmán](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigo_Mu%C3%B1oz_de_Guzm%C3%A1n), nacido en el siglo XII.

Sin embargo, esto no descarta la posibilidad de que el origen del topónimo "Guzmán" sea el comentado. ¿Qué teorías hay hasta la fecha acerca del origen de este topónimo?

Comment: Me parece más lógico que tenga origen ashkenazí oriental, siendo una variante de "gusman", un nombre ocupacional para un metalúrgico, del yiddish "gus", que significa "fundición" y "man" de hombre. Existe también una teoría que el nombre es de origen alemán y es una corrupción de "Gundemaro", un rey gótico.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que, siguiendo el razonamiento de la navaja de Ockham, lo más probable es que el topónimo Guzmán sea de origen visigodo: "Hombre bueno", ya que la cultura ashkenazi se formó con posterioridad al reino visigodo. Pudiera, en este mismo sentido, tener que ver con el nombre Gundemaro, de un rey visigodo español.

Comment: Buen comienzo, Santiago, y bienvenido al sitio.